# Stepping artifacts - Merging raster data in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, dem, bathymetry

I am working with a large number of raster datasets within multiple geodatabases in ArcGIS Pro. The original source data are imported from ASC format converted from UTM29N to WGS84 (Bilinear resampling used).

There are approximately 350 raster data sets that are then merged using ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder (Mosaic to New Raster). However the resultant merged dataset contains significant stepping artifacts within the data (like crosshatching or a chessboard). I have run the model with all resampling types available (nearest neighbor, bilinear, cubic).

NN resampling performs poorly, bilinear and cubic are improvements however the artifacts are then primarily visible in areas with low degrees of slope.

The individual raster data that make up the databases are all clean, high resolution data (5m & 10m) resolution with no artifacts visible. This only occurs when the new mosaicked dataset is created.

How can I remove/avoid this?

Comment: Welcome to a GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. You really ought to [Edit] the Question to state the pixel resolution in both SRIDs. Reprojection to geographic with too coarse a pixel size could easily cause such anomalies. You might try oversampling (2x or 3x) with bilinear interpolation before reprojection.

Comment: Also, nearest neighbor interpolation is, mostly, used for categorical variables (e.g., land use data). For contiuous data, like digital elevation model, bilinear or cubic interpolation is more appropriate (depending on your application).